# Not responce click on widget

Tags: android, click, widget

I have different controls on a widget (TextView, ImageView...). On some controls I set setOnClickPendingIntent (for example - tvInfo). It work. On click on TextView I get onReceive my widget.

```
protected final void addClickListener(String action, int layoutId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addClickListener " + action);
    Intent intent = new Intent(WidgetInfo.Context, getMainWidget());
    intent.setAction(action);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(WidgetInfo.Context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(layoutId, actionPendingIntent);
```

But if I click on another part of widget (where not set setOnClickPendingIntent) and then again on tvInfo. Nothing happens and onReceive not response. If I repeatedly click on tvIfo then onReceive work. Also, If I double click or even number of times and then again on tvInfo, onReceive response. onReceive not response only if I click on empty part of widget odd number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

- add setOnClickPendingIntent for top linearLayout of widget;
- set android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" for this linearLayout.